# Has anyone overcome Azure AI Translator issues with missing bullet points when translating documents?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, sdk, azure-ai-translator

I'm using the Azure AI Translator sdk in Python to translate whole documents and I find it does not handle bullet point lists well at all. In the translated document there are more often than not missing bullet points just left out entirely. The documents I'm translating for now are only PDF's.

Has anyone overcome this issue or had the same experience or perhaps a different experience?